# How to find the biggest sum of a given scope in a 2D array?

Tags: c

> **I need to know how to find the biggest sum of a given scope in a 2D array, preferably in C to improve the efficiency of the code give below and solve the problem.**

To understand this better, read the problem I need to solve below.

**Problem**

> The great city X is a grid of N rows and M columns. There are given
>   number of people living in each cell. You are asked to position the
>   telecommunication tower so that as many as people are satisfied. The
>   cellular tower can cover a rectangular area of Y rows and X columns.
>   Find the maximum number of people you can satisfy.

**Constrains**

```
1 <= N, M <= 1000
1 <= Y <= N, 1 <= X <= M
1 <= number of people in a cell <= 1000
```

Rectangular area covered by the celluar tower should not cover any cell partially.

**Input**

First line of the input will contain 4 digits N, M, Y and X respectively separated by spaces. Each of next N lines with contains integers of row 1 to N. Each row will M integers giving the number of people living in each cell separated by spaces.

**Output**

Output should contain only one integer, the maximum number of people you can satisfy.

***Sample Input***

```
4 5 2 3
3 1 1 1 2
2 5 6 7 1
1 2 9 9 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

***Sample Output***

```
38
```

**Explanation**

Maximum number of people can be satisfied by placing the tower covering 2x3 area that consists of 5, 6, 7, 2, 9 and 9 cells.

```
5 + 6 + 7 + 2 + 9 + 9 = 38
```

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int N, M, Y, X;
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &M, &Y, &X);

int max = 0;
int total = 0;

int data[N][M];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        scanf("%d",&(data[i][j]));    

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        total = 0;

            for(int l = 0; (l < Y) && (i + Y) <= N; l++)
            {

                for(int k = 0; (k < X) && (j + X <= M); k++)
                {
                    total += data[i+l][j+k];
                }

                if(total > max)
                    max = total;                       
        } 
    }  
}   

printf("%d",max);
return 0;
}
```

This code fails because it's too linear and takes a lot of time when a larger input is used.

You can try out the problem yourself, [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/ioi-sri-lanka-2015/challenges/number-grid)

Comment: Try thinking of how you'd solve the 1-D equivalent of the problem.  For example, consider a 1-D city with cells `{ 3, 5, 7, 6, 1 }` with a tower covering 3 cells.  Would you really check `3+5+7`, `5+7+6`, `7+6+1`?  Or is there something more efficient you can do?

Comment: still can't figure out! :( @MooseBoys

Comment: You can calculate `s = 3+5+7`, then `s += 6-3`, then `s += 1-5`.  After calculating the first sum, you only need to access two elements to generate subsequent ones, by removing the old leftmost one and adding the new rightmost.  The 2-D case is analogous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the main problem in your solution of Number Grid problem is nested `for` loops. The simplest optimization is to minimaze number of recalculations for each move of the scope.

I tryed the following changes in the original code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int N, M, Y, X;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &M, &Y, &X);

    int max = 0;
    int total = 0;

    int data[N][M];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            scanf("%d",&(data[i][j]));  
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // calculation of the first total and initial max
    int startTotal = 0;
    int r, c;
    for(r = 0; r < Y-1; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < X-1; c++)
        {
            startTotal += data[r][c];
        }
    }
    max = startTotal;

    for(int i = 0; i+Y <= N; i++)
    {
        // add next line
        for(int c = 0; c < X-1; c++)
        {
            startTotal += data[i+Y-1][c];
        }
        total = startTotal;
        for(int j = 0; j+X <= M; j++)
        {
            // add next column
            for(int r = i; r < i+Y; r++)
                total += data[r][j+X-1];
            // compare
            if(total > max)
            {
                max = total;
            }
            // subtract the first column
            for(int r = i; r < i+Y; r++)
                total -= data[r][j];
        }
        // subtract the first line
        for(int c = 0; c < X-1; c++)
        {
            startTotal -= data[i][c];
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    printf("%d",max);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tryed to run the program at hackerrank.com, and received

[image]